# Почему React webpack-dev-server выдаёт ошибку «Не найден bundle.js»?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю через yarn. Не создавал webpack.config. Выдаёт:

> GET http://localhost:8080/bundle.js 404 (Not Found).

Вот package. Установил mode `'production'`, чтобы он собрал этот файл, думал в этом проблема. В mode `'development'` также не находит.

```
{
  "name": "react-project-hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample React project to demonstrate how to set up enviroinment for React.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode production index.js"
  },
  "author": "Alex Park",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте `webpack-config` в вопрос

Comment: @Klimenkomud я его не создавал

Comment: А каким образом `webpack` вам будет ваш бандл собирать? Добавьте в вопрос структуру вашего проекта

Comment: https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/beginners-guide-to-webpack-how-to-start-a-basic-application-with-webpack-2-ebed3172fa8c Почитайте про конфигурацию вебпака

Comment: @Klimenkomud он у меня собирает успешно

Comment: @Klimenkomud делал по этому гайду [ссылка](https://codeburst.io/yet-another-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-a-react-project-part-1-bdc8a29aea22)вот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не создали `webpack.config.js` поэтому и видите ошибку о том, что файл `bundle.js` не найден, по причине того, что его никто не создал. Рекомендую внести следующие правки в `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-project-hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample React project to demonstrate how to set up env for React",
  "author": "Alex Park",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
  }
}
```

На что обратить внимание:

- Убрал `"main": "index.js"` - если у нас `webpack`, то это указывать уже ни к чему.
- Скрипт `start` - здесь есть небольшая корректива, если уж идти правильным путем, то запуск по-хорошему - это работа dev-версии, для текущей отладки, а вот построение - это как раз продакшн. Не знаю как у других, но на проектах, где я работаю - делают так.
- Скрипт `build` - построение сборки для продакшн.

Остальное осталось без изменений. Идем далее, создание файла `webpack.config.js`. Файл будет достаточно прост, в зависимости от режима вернет нам нужный модуль:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === 'development') {
    return require('./webpack.development.config');
  }

  return require('./webpack.production.config');
}
```

Как вы наверняка уже догадались, понадобится еще два файла. Это `webpack.development.config` и `webpack.production.config`. Тут уже кто на что горазд, указываем плагины, модули с правилами, и все что есть сопутствующее. Готовые примеры можно найти в документации к `webpack`:

- [Development](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/)
- [Production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/)

Пример для `webpack.development.config` (кстати, тут и указывается путь к `index.js` внутри `entry`):

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    print: './src/print.js'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Development'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

какие-то общие правила можно вынести в `webpack.common.js`, чтобы не писать одни и те же строки в двух файлах. Надеюсь немного ясности я привнес в понимание ответа на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack dev server не предназначен для сборки в продакшене. Сделайте 3 конфига как в официальном гайде: 1 - production, 1 - development, 1 - common. В development используйте webpack-dev-server, в production - собирайте обычным скриптом webpack --mode production.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

Comment: Понял, спасибо.